# Plugin not found with custom view helper

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers, actionviewhelper, viewhelper

I need some help with a custom view helper.

My folder structure is like this:

```
application
 - modules
 - - smjestaj
 - views
 - - helpers
 - - - LoadSkin.php
```

And if I go to `localhost/smjestaj` I get this error:

> Message: Plugin by name 'LoadSkin' was not found in the registry; used paths:
>   Smjestaj_View_Helper_: /Users/davs/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/1/application/modules/smjestaj/views/helpers/
>   ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/
>   Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/

I tried to register my helper in application.ini but with no luck.

If I copy my folders `view->helpers->LoadSkin.php` to my module smjestaj that works, but I don't think that is the right way to do it.

Comment: How are you requesting the helper in your PHP script?

Comment: What is the name of your view helper class? Zend is kind of picky regarding the name

Comment: Show us source code of your view helper.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for: [Resolve view helper location from within the controller or form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978389/zend-resolve-view-helper-location-from-within-the-controller-or-form)

Note that the paths Zend is looking at are different from the one you actually have your helpers in. You must inform Zend about where you keep the helpers. The quoted question offers two solutions: doing it in the bootstrap or in application.ini.